# Парсинг повторяющихся тегов используя Android Sax Parser

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlparser, sax

Есть Xml Sax парсер, парсит новостную ленту.

```
public List<RSSItem> parse() {
    final RSSItem currentMessage = new RSSItem();
    final RootElement root = new RootElement(NAMESPACE, "rss");
    final List<RSSItem> messages = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    Element channel = root.getChild(NAMESPACE, "channel");

    Element item = channel.getChild(NAMESPACE, ITEM);

    item.setEndElementListener(new EndElementListener() {
        public void end() {
            messages.add(currentMessage.copy());
        }
    });


    item.getChild(NAMESPACE, TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setTitle(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild(NAMESPACE, LINK).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setLink(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild(NAMESPACE, DESCRIPTION).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setDescription(body);
        }
    });
    item.getChild("http://news.yandex.ru", "full-text").setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setContent(body);
        }
    });   
   item.getChild(NAMESPACE, CATEGORY).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setCategory(body);
        }
    });
```

Тег "item" парсит с конца и по этому выводит только одно значение (Some Text7). Нужно как-то переписать код:

```
item.getChild(NAMESPACE, CATEGORY).setEndTextElementListener(new     EndTextElementListener() {
        public void end(String body) {
            currentMessage.setCategory(body);
        }
    });
```

.

```
<rss xmlns="http://backend.userland.com/rss2">
<channel>
  <title>Some text</title>
  <item>
     <title>Some title</title>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text1]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text2]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text3]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text4]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text5]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text6]]></category>
     <category><![CDATA[Some Text7]]></category>
  </item>
```

Как получить данные из всех повторяющихся тегов "category"? Новостная [лента](http://www.postfactum.ks.ua/feed) полностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему используя XmlPullParser